# Using SkiaSharp how would one darken the entire image (excluding the background)

Tags: xamarin, skiasharp

The below snippet darkens the entire image but I wish to darken all the parts except the background. How would one go about doing this? You will notice the png below has no background so I am not sure why this doesn't work.

I am guessing it is something to do with how the image is loaded into memory from the file and alpha channels etc.

```
 SKImage image = SKImage.FromBitmap(resourceBitmap);

 var skImageFilter = SKImageFilter.CreateColorFilter(SKColorFilter.CreateBlendMode(AppColors.DarkGreyColor.ToSKColor(),
                SKBlendMode.Darken));



 image = image.ApplyImageFilter(
                skImageFilter, new SKRectI(0,0, image.Width,image.Height), new SKRectI(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), out SKRectI subSet, out SKPoint point);
```

[image]

Comment: `SKColorFilter` can only be a global filter on the image.You can upload your want image,that will be helpful.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I have added the example image.

Comment: Ok,it looks like a icon.Do you try use a backgroundless PNG icon?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT if you open it in an editor you will see it is backgroundless.

Comment: Ok, you try this `using (SKPaint paint = new SKPaint())
            {
                paint.BlendMode = SKBlendMode.DstIn;
                canvas.DrawBitmap(matteBitmap, x, y, paint);
            }` .Or you can try use renderer method to do that in ios or android.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by wrapping the `SKImageFilter`, taken from this other stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74411192/ignore-transparent-pixels-for-non-separable-blend-modes):

```cs
SKImageFilter.CreateBlendMode(SKBlendMode.DstIn,
    SKImageFilter.CreateColorFilter(SKColorFilter.CreateBlendMode(AppColors.DarkGreyColor.ToSKColor(), SKBlendMode.Darken)));
```