# Ignore transparent pixels for non-separable blend modes

Tags: skiasharp

I'm using non-separable blend modes like this

```cs
SKColorFilter.CreateBlendMode(SKColors.Red, SKBlendMode.Color)
```

to replace "colored" pixel for an image (e.g. eye color).

Unfortunately in this sample this will also transform transparent pixels to red.
Is there are way to ignore transparent pixel for non-separable blend modes?

EDIT

This is the workaround I ended up with:

```cs
public static SKImage Colorize(this SKImage image, SKColor color)
{
    using SKBitmap bitmap = SKBitmap.FromImage(image);
    using SKCanvas canvas = new(bitmap);

    using SKPaint paint = new()
    {
        ImageFilter = SKImageFilter.CreateColorFilter(SKColorFilter.CreateBlendMode(color, SKBlendMode.Color)),
        BlendMode = SKBlendMode.SrcIn,
    };

    canvas.DrawImage(image, SKRect.Create(image.Width, image.Height), paint);

    return SKImage.FromBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then when initializing SKPaint with your color filter you'd set Blend mode to SrcIn, the transparency of canvas would work as mask for what you are drawing:

```
    new SKPaint
    {
        ...
        ColorFilter = SKColorFilter.CreateBlendMode(SKColors.Red, SKBlendMode.Color),
        BlendMode = SKBlendMode.SrcIn
    }
```

Edit:

As per comment, solution using just the ApplyImageFilter method might look like this:

```
public static SKImage Colorize(SKImage image, SKColor color)
{
    var filter = SKImageFilter.CreateBlendMode(SKBlendMode.DstIn,
        SKImageFilter.CreateColorFilter(SKColorFilter.CreateBlendMode(color, SKBlendMode.Color))
    );
    return image.ApplyImageFilter(filter, image.Info.Rect, image.Info.Rect, out _, out SKPointI _);
}
```

Note the SKBlendMode is DstIn here as now the image itself is the background for the filter.

Comment: You are right. In fact I was searching for a SKImage.ApplyImageFilter solution (not explained very well in the question though), but I'm using a workaround now based / similar to your suggestion (see my edited question). If you have a better solution, let me know - thanks anyway :)

Comment: I added the ApplyImageFilter solution, pretty sure it's what you are looking for :)

Comment: This is great, thanks again. One last question - do you have any documentation hints? I did not find anything useful... what is background / foreground for CreateBlendMode? What is the input / output for each wrapped filter?

Comment: I don't have much of a hint. After a while you get this intuitively. Rendering target is always the background, so when you ApplyImageFilter, the rendering target is the image itself, while in previous solution it was the canvas. As I don't remember all the blend modes, I always refer to https://skia.org/docs/user/api/skblendmode_overview/ or actually https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation as it is 1:1 but more explicit image examples :)